# Inserting multiple textboxes in db through query result issue

Tags: php, sql, insert, textbox

here i am again with an amateur question about executing a query statement for multiple textboxes.

I made the following code, standard there are 4 textboxes but with javascript the user has a option to add more textboxes, which will be having continued naming following     `productg[4]` so `productg[5]` etc. I need this to work with these 4 for now, thus the reason i have not posted the javascript part.

When executing this code, i do get a result as echo with all the textboxesvalues that were filled in, but in my database only 1 row is added, when i expect there to be 4.

If more information is needed to give me sufficient advise, i´ll provide it as best as i can.

## HTML

```
<div id="productgroepen">
    <div>
        <label>Product groep 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="productg[1]" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Product groep 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="productg[2]" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Product groep 3</label>
        <input type="text" name="productg[3]" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Product groep 4</label>
        <input type="text" name="productg[4]" />
    </div>
</div>
```

## PHP

```
    $total = 4;
    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['productg']) && isset($_POST['productg'][$i]))
        {
            $product = $_POST['productg'][$i];
            $productquery = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO productgroepen SET id = 'LAST_INSERT_ID()' , levid ='$hidresult' , productgroep = '$product'");
            if($productquery === false)
            {
                throw new Exception('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($conn) );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$total = 4;
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    if(isset($_POST['productg']) && isset($_POST['productg'][$i])){
        //still needs some check whether $_POST['productg'][$i] contains an acceptable value
        $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO productgroepen SET levid='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $hidresult)."', productgroep='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['productg'][$i])."'");
        if($result === false)
            throw new Exception('Query failed: '.mysqli_error($conn) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question, i updated my question with the suggested for loop solution, i removed the `if(isset)` because i don't need these checks at the minute, it´s about functionality for now.

It still gives me 4x the echo query, with the 4 values i entered in the different textboxes, but it only adds 1 record to my database so the issue still persists.

Comment: Why remove error checking? Error checking is the best way (even if testing) to see what is going wrong. The check whether the query succeeded or not is the most important. Probably one of the queries is failing due to missing / wrong / invalid IDs. So add the query check and see what happens.

Comment: As stated, i'm an amateur and i apologize beforehand for dumb questions.
I updated my post again, this time i get this response 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Query failed.' in /data/web/dropshipment.domainhosting.nl/htdocs/leverancierregistratie.php:187 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /directory/sub/website/htdocs/file.php on line 187

Comment: Okay there we have it. The query is failing :-). Just changed my code. Please execute it like that to see why the query is failing. (added throw new Exception('Query failed: '.mysqli_error($conn) ) )

Comment: I was one step ahead of you in looking up the good old mysqli_error, it seems i was using it right by not parsing a $conn in it.

With that respond of the error, it said i had duplicate entry, i messed up on the database side, i will update my script when it's working for people who might need it in the future.

Wimpie, Thanks alot for your support on this ridicilous stupid problem !

Comment: Proper error handling and checking will fix this for you in the future. Just try to always check for errors and throw exceptions :-0

Comment: Yes, doing that directly would've spared me alot of time.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Wimpie has solved my problem, and gave me a more insight on sql errorcatching so i've updated my question with the answer, if anyone is interested in the javascript side to add more textboxes, i'll be happy to post it.

The issue at hand was that i made the levid primary in my database, which doesn't allow duplicate entries.